# keras.get_ssion().graph is not working in tensorflow2.x

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I could graphs of keras model by code below in tensorflow1.x

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
...
graph=K.get_session().graph


graph_def=graph.as_graph_def()
print(graph_def)
```

[image: result in tensorflow1.x]

However, when I change tensorflow version to 2.x, it does not working.
I got the result like a picture below in tensorflow2.1.

[image: result in tensorflow2.1]

How can I get graphs of keras model in tensorflow2.x?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow migration guide would be the place where you can start -

[Migrate your TensorFlow 1 code to TensorFlow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate)